# Cocoa structs and NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, struct

I have an NSMutableArray that I'm trying to store and access some structs.  How do I do this?  'addObject' gives me an error saying "Incompatible type for argument 1 of addObject".  Here is an example ('in' is a NSFileHandle, 'array' is the NSMutableArray):

```
//Write points
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    struct Point p;
    buff = [in readDataOfLength:1];
    [buff getBytes:&(p.x) length:sizeof(p.x)];
    [array addObject:p];
}

//Read points
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    struct Point p = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%i", p.x);
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As mentioned, `NSValue` can wrap a plain struct using  [`+value:withObjCType:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-value_withObjCType_) or [`-initWithBytes:objCType:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-initWithBytes_objCType_):

```
// add:
[array addObject:[NSValue value:&p withObjCType:@encode(struct Point)]];

// extract:
struct Point p;
[[array objectAtIndex:i] getValue:&p];
```

See the [Number and Value guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG) for more examples.

Comment: I don't know who you are, but I will find you and get you a beer!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting errors because `NSMutableArray` can only accept references to objects, so you should wrap your structs in a class:

```
@interface PointClass {
     struct Point p;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) struct Point p;
```

This way, you can pass in instances of `PointClass`.

**Edit**: As mentioned above and below, NSValue already provides this in a more generic way, so you should go with that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use NSValue, or in some cases it might make sense to use a dictionary instead of a struct.